# PHP time() give differents results in the same moment

Tags: php, time

I created a php multiplayer word game using the time () function to synchronize it.

It works great except that sometimes the time value function gives different results in the same moment that make disorder !!
To explain that, i make a php file with this code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(1000);">
<?php
echo time();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I open it with two different chrome user, and i get an offset of ~ 20s !
i delate the history of one of the chrome user and that fixe the problem !

Please explanation & solution

Comment: Maybe that is 20ms instead of 20s? Have you double-checked for that?

Comment: @alexandernst `time()` returns seconds.

Comment: yes i use time() & not microtime()

Comment: In server-client games there always is a lag. So if two clients will send requests at the same time does not mean that requests will arrive to server at the same time too. And even if they arrive OS on server may interrupt thread that executes one of clients request so times will mismatch. If you use caching for one client cache might be empty so it will request db or other external data-storage, that will also give time differences.

Comment: @PLB Yeah, but seriously, 20 seconds?

Comment: maybe that will be happen with many client connected

Comment: @galymzhan Yes, it's really huge difference. All I can think of is db operation when cache gets cleaned.

Comment: but i log just with these two chrome users and the offset is ~20s!

Comment: @MohamedSakka Can you add more context to your question (i.e. exactly what you're doing)? We are lacking quite big information to help you.

Comment: i make a simple multiplayer php word game, and i use the time() function to synchronize it, some times i get this probleme of time difference that make disorder !

Comment: i delate the history of one of the chrome user and that fixe the problem !

Comment: @MohamedSakka do you HAVE TO refresh the page via javascript? there is other ways to refresh every x seconds

Comment: i use setinterval function to get regulary data from server ! is there other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

since OP asks for another solution: "i use setinterval function to get regulary data from server ! is there other solutions ?"

Yes, for example you can Refresh every 10 seconds by:

```
<?php $refresh_time = 10; ?>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $refresh_time; ?>" />
</head>
```

please note: refreshing whole page every 1 second to get data from server is a bad idea.

suggestion: Why not trying ajax calls for getting data?

**TRICKING CHROME NOT TO USE CACHE (if thats the case):**

If google chrome caching is a pain, try doing this: instead of reloading the same url, add a parameter to the url that is new every time, so browser will not try to use any cache. like this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
        setTimeout("window.location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname+'&t=<?php echo time();?>'",timeoutPeriod);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: yes i use multipul get jquery call every 1 second 

    <script>var int=self.setInterval(function(){boot()},1000);</script>

    function boot(){
    $.post('content/boot.php', function(data) {
    ........      
    }, "json");
    };

Comment: but hier the problem seems to be related to the chrome browser and not to the server ! maybe be the cache